# why I don't get the URL to access the http cloud function I create?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

[image]

so I make http trigger function to get all events from my firestore like the image above.

firestore.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

// initialize database
admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings)

const eventRef = db.collection('event')



module.getAllEventsFromFirestore = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response) => {

    try {
        const events = await eventRef.get()
        response.status(200).send(`number of event is ${event.size}`)
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error)
    }


})
```

and my index.js

```
const {getAllEventsFromFirestore} = require("./firestore")
```

after deploying the function, I expect will get the URL to access that http trigger function on my terminal, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will only give you a URL the first time you deploy the function.  If you update the function after the first deploy, it won't print the URL.  You can get the URL of the function by going to the Firebase console and view your functions there.  The URL will be available on the Functions dashboard page.

If you would like to see a change in behavior of the Firebase CLI, [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: I have tried to find it in firebase console like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTozZ.png, but I can't find it. could you please in what section I can find it in firebase console sir ?

Comment: You might be looking at a different project in the console than the one where it was deployed.